# How to use Jest/Enzyme to test React components with JSS style encapsulation?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, enzyme, jestjs, jss

I'm struggling a little bit with testing my React components with Jest because of JSS component encapsulation.

Pseudo code example:

JSS(`style.js`):

```
export default {
    pinkOnYellow: {
       color: 'pink',
       backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    }
}
```

React component

```
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles'
import compose from 'recompose/compose'
import classes from './style.js'

const MyComponent = ({classes}) =>{
   <div className={classes.pinkOnYellow} />
}

export default compose(withStyles(style))(MyComponent)
```

When component is instantiated `classes` object will look somewhat like:

```
{pinkOnYellow: 'MyComponent-pinkOnYellow-32423'}
```

Therefore component HTML will look like

```
<div class="MyComponent-pinkOnYellow-32423" />
```

That means when writing Jest/Enzyme test I can't use class selectors easily because I don't know what class name was mapped to.
I found some solutions and I'm unhappy with both because they're super restricting:

1st

```
it('should be shallow as my soul', () => {
   const imageGallery = shallow(<ImageGallery images={images} />)
   expect(timageGallery.find('[class^=pinkOnYellow]')).toBe(1)
})
```

2nd (doesn't work with shallow)

```
function getClassesByEnzymeInstance(instance, className) {
   const componentName = instance.name()
   const classNameMapped = `.${instance.find(componentName).props('classes').classes[className]}`
   return classNameMapped
}

it('should be not as shallow', () => {
   const imageGallery = mount(<ImageGallery images={images} />)
   const mappedClassName = getClassesByEnzymeInstance(ImageGallery, 'pinkOnYellow')
   expect(timageGallery.find(mappedClassName)).toBe(1)
})
```

3rd one will be probably wrapping `classes` object in a `Proxy` which will return keys instead of values when environment is test but is seems hacky and leads to having differences in component depending on environment which I'd like to avoid.

As I mentioned both solutions are very restricted therefore I'll appreciate any advice/ides which can point me in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are testing isolated components and there is no class names conflicts possible. In this case you can define your own class names generator http://cssinjs.org/js-api?v=v9.0.0#generate-your-own-class-names and use simple style object keys as class name.

Comment: link gives 404 not found.